# Force live video on AVPlayer

Tags: ios, delay, avplayer, latency, http-live-streaming

I have initialized an `AVPlayer` with a URL pointing to a HLS live streaming video. The video is not played automatically but `AVPlayerViewController` wants me to hit the play button (even with `playImmediately(atRate: 1.0)` set). This creates a discrepancy among users watching the show when I must be sure everyone sees the same thing at the same time, therefore, I was wondering how can I make sure everyone sees the same thing. How can I force the player to go live whenever it falls behind? Thank you